# Submit an httpRequest method post to an apache server with java se

Tags: java, apache, post

i'm trying to use a website from my java application as i'd do through my browser; it's the first time i'm trying something like this and i'm afraid i'm missing something.

I'm using apache httpcore libraries to do the http requests with the post method, with wireshark i've seen the parameters in the post request and i've added them to the request i do with java; the same for the headers.

If i sniff the request made with java i can't capture the http post request, but only the tcp traffic.

This is how i do the request:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx");

httpPost.setHeader("Host", "xxx.xxx:xxxx");
.
.
.

HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter("aaaa", "bbbb");
.
.
.

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Am i missing something?

I should check something else?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply a body with your post request, which you do so by calling the .setEntity(HttpEntity) method on your HttpPost.

```
  private void sendToPostProxy(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
      //the url to forward too
      String url = "http://127.0.0.1:"+proxyPort+request.getRequestURI()
              +(request.getQueryString()==null?"":"?"+request.getQueryString());
      HttpPost get = new HttpPost(url);
      //I am streaming requests straight through, but there are many Entity types you can use
      get.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(request.getInputStream(), request.getContentLength()));
      sendToProxy(request, response, get);
  }
  private void sendToProxy(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response,HttpRequestBase get) throws IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    Enumeration headers = request.getHeaderNames();
    //copy headers
    while(headers.hasMoreElements()){
        String next = String.valueOf(headers.nextElement());
        String header = request.getHeader(next);
        if (!get.containsHeader(next)&&!"Content-Length".equalsIgnoreCase(next))
            get.addHeader(next, header);
    }
    try{
    //perform post
    HttpResponse proxied = client.execute(get);
    //set client headers
    for (Header h : proxied.getAllHeaders()){
        response.setHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
    }
    //stream to client
    HttpEntity body = proxied.getEntity();
    body.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        get.abort();
    }
}
```